# Bootstrap Sass with HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass, bootstrap-5

I have created my html file on VS Code and stylized it using Bootstrap. I made another Sass files specifying the changes in colour, font etc. and imported it's compiled version in the html. However, now the webpage isn't appearing the way it should when we open it using a browser, and it is appearing the way it is stylized only when I use the Live Server extension on VS Code. What should I do so that appears the same way it appears on the Live Server?

Comment: Could you please share with us your code?

Comment: The sass file? or the html?

Comment: The problem could be that the CSS resources are not present on the live server or the path is different, can you post a link to the live site so people can inspect the code please?